# Strategy to destroy the two red monsters at the end of Ghosts 'n Goblins?

Tags: ghosts-n-goblins

At the final level of Ghosts 'n Goblins, the only weapon you can finish the level with is the shield.  I have not been able to destroy the two red monsters at the end.  If I get close enough to hit them with the shield, they swoop down and kill me.  Even if I just stay far away, they still swoop down and kill me.

What is a good strategy to destroy the two red monsters?  I am playing the arcade game, not the NES port.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit irritated becaus your question is flagged "Ghouls 'n Ghosts". I don't remember the last boss to be two monsters!

I think you mean the Game "Ghosts 'n Goblins" and by two red monster i think you mean the two Red Arremers in "Stage 6", the final Stage is the 7th!

[image]

"Well you should encounter the Red Arremer on the left first, and the Red Arremer on the right second. Make sure that this is the case so that you can engage the left one without fear of attack from the right one. You must do your best to attack each Red Arremer one at a time. Lure the left Red Arremer down a few levels with the ladders in order to ensure that the Red Arremers can not gang up on you."

Thats the hint given by Strategywiki (Ghosts 'n Goblins)

Comment: They're called Red Arremers, not 'Satans'.

Comment: in the German Version they say: Satans ;) But iam ok with "Red Arremers"!